# Ubuntu 20.04 Lock screen spawns multiple logins

Tags: login, 20.04, lock-screen, multiple-users

I have recently upgraded to 20.04 from 19.10. At the end of the work day I typically Lock my screen and go home for the evening. When I come in the next day I am able to enter my password but the login screen just hangs. If I press Ctrl+Alt+F2 I am given my desktop with all windows I previously had open. After this event I can open a terminal and use the "who" command to see that I am now logged in twice. Once on tty7, and once on tty8 for example... How can I troubleshoot / fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I was using sddm from when I was using the plasma desktop. By uninstalling kubuntu-desktop and changing from sddm to gdm3 the problem seems to be fixed!

Check out this link for example commands:

[Switch Display Manager in Ubuntu 20.04](https://techpiezo.com/linux/switch-display-manager-in-ubuntu-20-04/)